# How to make a Java loop not print vertically

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to print a square using two half pyramids but it's displaying it vertically instead of printing out a square. I also encounter this problem in other patterns that I create using loops and I don't know how to resolve it. Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
    for (int k = 5; k >= i; k--) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Expected result:

A
B
B
B
B
B

A
A
B
B
B
B

A
A
A
B
B
B

A
A
A
A
B
B

A
A
A
A
A
B

Comment: you can use System.out.print it wont print new line.

Answer (score 2):

Use `print` instead of `println`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
    for (int k = 5; k >= i; k--) {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: This results in expected output

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is replace the println with print

```
system.out.println("A");
```

the above code would print the text and then shift the curser to the next line

```
system.out.print("B");
```

this should do the thing